# Array seems to drop first element

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I make a request to a database and get the following data from it:

> array(5) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#39 (3) { ["route_id"]=> string(4) "1103" ["route_date"]=> string(10) "2013-12-24" ["truck_id"]=> string(1) "0" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#38 (3) { ["route_id"]=> string(4) "1104" ["route_date"]=> string(10) "2013-12-25" ["truck_id"]=> string(1) "0" } [2]=> object(stdClass)#37 (3) { ["route_id"]=> string(4) "1468" ["route_date"]=> string(10) "2013-12-25" ["truck_id"]=> string(1) "0" } [3]=> object(stdClass)#36 (3) { ["route_id"]=> string(4) "1469" ["route_date"]=> string(10) "2013-12-25" ["truck_id"]=> string(1) "0" } [4]=> object(stdClass)#35 (3) { ["route_id"]=> string(4) "1105" ["route_date"]=> string(10) "2013-12-26" ["truck_id"]=> string(1) "0" } }

From there, I want to rearrange the data into a multidimensional array using the following code:

```
$i = 0; 
$j = 0;
foreach($routes_array as $key => $route)
        {
            if($route->route_date === $routes_array[$key + 1]->route_date)
            {
                var_dump($route); 
                echo("<br/>");
                $day[$i][$j] = $route;
                echo("assigning rought to i:".$i." j: ".$j);
                echo("<br/>");
                $j++; 
            }
            else
            {
                var_dump($route); 
                echo("<br/>");
                $day[$i][$j] = $route;
                echo("assigning rought to i:".$i." j: ".$j);
                echo("<br/>");
                $i++;
                $j = 0; 
            }
        }
        echo("<br/>");
        var_dump($day);
```

The output of the `echo`'s in the code above is:

> object(stdClass)#39 (3) { ["route_id"]=> string(4) "1103" ["route_date"]=> string(10) "2013-12-24" ["truck_id"]=> string(1) "0" } 
>   assigning rought to i:0 j: 0
>
> object(stdClass)#38 (3) { ["route_id"]=> string(4) "1104" ["route_date"]=> string(10) "2013-12-25" ["truck_id"]=> string(1) "0" } 
>   assigning rought to i:1 j: 0
>
> object(stdClass)#37 (3) { ["route_id"]=> string(4) "1468" ["route_date"]=> string(10) "2013-12-25" ["truck_id"]=> string(1) "0" } 
>   assigning rought to i:1 j: 1
>
> object(stdClass)#36 (3) { ["route_id"]=> string(4) "1469" ["route_date"]=> string(10) "2013-12-25" ["truck_id"]=> string(1) "0" } 
>   assigning rought to i:1 j: 2
>
> object(stdClass)#35 (3) { ["route_id"]=> string(4) "1105" ["route_date"]=> string(10) "2013-12-26" ["truck_id"]=> string(1) "0" } 
>   assigning rought to i:2 j: 0

The problem is when I do the last `var_dump` I get this:

> array(3) { [0]=> int(2) [1]=> array(3) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#38 (3) { ["route_id"]=> string(4) "1104" ["route_date"]=> string(10) "2013-12-25" ["truck_id"]=> string(1) "0" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#37 (3) { ["route_id"]=> string(4) "1468" ["route_date"]=> string(10) "2013-12-25" ["truck_id"]=> string(1) "0" } [2]=> object(stdClass)#36 (3) { ["route_id"]=> string(4) "1469" ["route_date"]=> string(10) "2013-12-25" ["truck_id"]=> string(1) "0" } } [2]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#35 (3) { ["route_id"]=> string(4) "1105" ["route_date"]=> string(10) "2013-12-26" ["truck_id"]=> string(1) "0" } } }

You will notice that the first element `[0][0]` does not have the first object.

What am I doing wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

To detect an error add var_dump($day) after each iteration of *foreach* cycle (before closing brackets of *foreach* cycle)